# apns device token not generating with production certificate

Tags: iphone

I have read ray's awsome tutorials on apns from there
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2

and i have implemented them with development certificate and every thing is working fine, but now when i have implemented it with production certificate, the device token has stop generating. i have created new App Id for production and also new Production Push SSL Certificate and i have also created the .pem files but some how the device token is not generating, plz. guide me in this coz i am stuck here, even this notification is not being called

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSString* oldToken = [dataModel deviceToken];

    NSString* newToken = [deviceToken description];
    newToken = [newToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    newToken = [newToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", newToken);

    [dataModel setDeviceToken:newToken];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TokenRecieved" object:nil];

    if ([dataModel joinedChat] && ![newToken isEqualToString:oldToken])
    {
        [self postUpdateRequest];
    }
}
```

plz. guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason of this type of behavior can be that you have not registered your application for `RemoteNotifications`. To register it for apns you will need to write following code in your Application Delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

```
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge ];
```

It will register your device for Badge and Alert kind of notification. To verify whether application is registered or not you can go in **settings>notification>your application** if its their with these two kind of notification types then your application will be ready to call the delegate method and receive notification(if the switch in settings is on).

Moreover, it would be helpful if you implement `application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:` method and log errors if any.

Thanks

Comment: Thanx Ravin but i had added that line "[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge ];" in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions before, still the device token is not generating, and your second point about log errors, can you explain a little that point that how to log errors, meanwhile i have implemented application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: in my app but dont have any idea how to log errors, plz. guide. Thanx

Comment: By log error means: If you are using Developer profile to sign application then NSLog it on console to see whether device has registered itself for remote notification or not. But if you are using Distribution profile to sign app then use Alert. So, basically in this delegate you will need to show an alert to user showing that app is unable to register for apns.

Comment: Thanx Ravin i will do this, but this will not solve the problem, i actually want to know why app is not generating device token or why app is not getting registered for apns with distribution profile, i am stuck on this from quiet a long time now, is there any solution?

Comment: Hey, this is what this error message will tell you, why application has failed to register for remote notification. Have your tried this? what does it say?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly a same problem a while ago. Even `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` was not called after calling `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes`.

One reason I have encountered and spent hours to find out was that I had an old provisioning profile which is associated with an APN certificate. All I needed to do was re-creating (not only redownloading) provisioning profiles for production and re-install them again.

If you have created an APN certificate AFTER creating provisioning profiles, this step might help you.